# CSV downloads as HTM

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, web

I am having a huge problem in all browsers.

I have a site where clients can download a csv file that contains detail they need.

The problem I am having is that the csv file either downloads with no extension or as a htm file.

In the code I am specifying the file name with .csv, the file on the server is also a .csv.

The code is as follows

```
context.Response.Buffer = true;
context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();                    
context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", @"attachment,     
     filename=" + ((string)Path.GetFileName(downloadFilePath)));
context.Response.WriteFile(downloadFilePath);
context.Response.Flush();
context.Response.Close();
```

I have tried `context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";` and `context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";`.

It is running on IIS6.

Does anybody know what could be causing this?

Comment: @NicholasMurray _I am having a huge problem in all browsers._ read the text.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses - and what browsers can you infer from 'all browsers'? IE 5, Firefox 1?

Comment: Have you tried enclosing the filename in double-quotes?

Comment: Using Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), you should provide the HTTP request you're sending to the server and then the HTTP response you're getting back. That will provide everything necessary to diagnose your problem with more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have worked out why files are not downloading as CSV.

its because the file name has spaces in it, so I need to enclose the filename so that it doesnt cut off at the space.

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your [verbatim string literal](http://dotnetslackers.com/CSharp/re-51752_The_Chash_String_Literal.aspx) is on a single-line in your source, have you tried replacing the `,` in your `Content-Disposition` header with a `;`? Examples I have found always use a semi-colon there.

It also might be safer to use quotes around your filename to protect the header from special characters:

```
context.Response.AppendHeader(
    "Content-Disposition",
    string.Format(
        "attachment; filename=\"{0}\"",
        Path.GetFileName(downloadFilePath)));
```

Comment: Yes, that would make it compliant with section 19.5.1 of the relevant RFC: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html

Comment: Since verbatim literal isn't needed at all in OP's example, I suspect that it's in fact a multi line string. Btw, escape character doesn't work with verbatim literals, try changing that constant to `@"attachment; filename=""{0}"""` or, even better, remove the `@` prefix.

Comment: Let me try and the questions from my question

All browsers - FF, IE and Chrome

context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", @"attachment; filename=" + ((string)Path.GetFileName(downloadFilePath)));

This is all on one line in the code file

Comment: @Groo Thanks for pointing that out - I had meant to remove the @ symbol whilst modifying the code. As you say, it's not required for this to work.

Comment: Will the suggestion above make a difference as to it being recognised as a csv if the extension is csv

Comment: I just read my comment and it didn't make much sense.
What I meant was, would your suggestions above make a difference to how it is downloaded from the browser, the extension on the 'downloadfilepath' is set to csv already, so why does it download as a htm????